# Does Angular require TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have just had a look at the [Angular quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) document and it shows the usage of TypeScript. A thought has just popped into my mind:

> Does Angular require TypeScript?

Then a few seconds later:

> How does Angular relate to TypeScript?

A quick Google of the first question does not lead to a direct answer. As I can’t be the first or the last person to ask this question, I am posting it to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does Angular require Typescript

No it doesn't. You can use normal Javascript also. The designers wanted to give as many choices as possible so the framework is easily accessible by many people. The Typescript compiler generates ES6/ES5 compliant code you can consume.

The Angular2 "[Getting Started](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html)" shows all examples in both TypeScript and ES5.

> How does Angular relate to Typescript

All the source code will be written in Typescript.

However, they also need to support transpiling to Dart (using [ts2dart](https://github.com/angular/ts2dart)), so some parts of the code base are written just so transpiling to Dart is possible. For example, Dart has a notion of constant expressions, so they have to use `CONST_EXPR` in the TS code (which makes the code base more complicated). This is only an implementation detail and user code does not have to worry about this.